# How to extract specific data from HTML files?

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have some code that will extract pairs of data from an HTML file using BS4:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
readfile = """
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="generator"
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <table align="center" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" width="650">
  <tr>
    <td>
    <font size="1"> Title1</font>
    <br /> </td>
    <td>
    <font size="1"> TItle2 type</font>
    <br /> </td>
    <td>
    <font size="1"> Title3</font>
    <br /> 
    <font size="2">value1</font></td>
    <td>
    <font size="1"> Title4 ID</font>
    <br /> 
    <font size="2">value2</font></td>
  </tr>
 """

soup = BeautifulSoup(readfile, "html.parser")
 tables = soup.findChildren('table')

for title in soup.find_all("font", {"size": "1"}):
    value = title.find_next_sibling("font", {"size": "2"})
    print (title.text, ":", value.text if value else "No Value")
```

Let's say that I have 30 rows in total. I only want 4 of the value pairs so I can then insert them into a rdbms.

Should I try then to use a list of the size:1 values I want get the size:2 value? Have looked up some examples on BS4 and it is not sinking in. 
Thanks

Comment: What is your desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd want to get first four pairs into a RDBMS, then giving a count variable and condition should suffice, like below.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
readfile = open("html.parser",'r')
soup = BeautifulSoup(readfile)

tables = soup.findChildren('table')

count = 0 
for i in soup.find_all("font", {"size": "1"}):
    value = i.find_next_sibling("font", {"size": "2"})
    if value is not None and count < 4:
       print (i.text, ":", value.text if value else "No Value")
       count = count + 1
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If I wanted the 1st 4, this would be the answer. And I should have been more specific. That is my fault. How do I select specific values from a list of 30 values. These will be the same for every file. Thank again!

Comment: Can you be more specific. Can you paste the exact html you're trying to parse from and what would need from it.The reason is that each of the tags in a html will differ from another tag by some unique id or attribute.So it would be easy for me to process if you paste the exact html that you're trying to parse from.

Comment: @Akayla: unfortunately the code is proprietary so I am not able to share it. I can say this: The HTML is one big table. So they used TD to create the table, TR to create the rows. They did not use the TC to name the cells. So that is why I have to use font: size to find stuff. Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: if you don't have any property which is unique in the all such tables and rows, then my suggestion would be to  put all of the value pairs to a 2D array and use regular expressions or conditions to select the requisite data from the array.You can also do this in one step while searching html as well.

Comment: I am going to upvote your answer as it comes the closest to my needs. Thanks for your time.